# RenderDoc inject into Google chrome failing

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps, renderdoc

Hi so I am trying to start chrome with white tab(no graphical api) following this [Google maps to 3D model tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmLXgt0sfq8) and part of it instructs to inject RenderDoc into Google chrome but the injection is failing

I'm suspecting that this is what is causing the injection to fail is that chrome is loading with graphical api involved:
I made a shortcut with Target in properties holding" C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "SET RENDERDOC_HOOK_EGL=0 && START "" ^"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe^" --no-sandbox --gpu-startup-dialog""
Using it opens this
[image]
But it should be like this
[image]
And can inject into it
[image]
But when I click the ok button in the pop up "GPU starts with pid: 2408" puts me out and when I try to reinject does this
[image]

Any idea how I can fix this?
Tried different versions of RenderDoc (1.17 and 1.24), running on cmd instead of shortcut and restarting machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going crazy with this problem....
Chrome restart several times, before restarting I noticed injection success with upper status bar visible, but when chrome restart last time injection fails.
I suspect that chrome has a system to detect injection and try several methods to block it, until a new restarted gpu process has avoided it.
I'm actually searching in this direction to solve the problem (if I'm right).

Confimation of this : https://www.securityweek.com/chrome-block-apps-injecting-its-processes/

...So I'll try a chrome version before 72 of January 2019, when chrome try to blocks all injections...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this will be able to solve your problem but I have been dealing with a similar issue recently and the way I solved it was going into task manager and manually closing all chrome related processes.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome employs effective anti-injection methods that were implemented several years ago for security purposes. However, if you intend to perform injections into a web browser, you may opt for your own chromium implementation like CEF to incorporate new features and bug fixes. I advice you to avoid using older versions of Chrome, as they often contain numerous bugs, particularly when navigating newer websites. I speak from personal experience and suggest staying up-to-date with the latest Chromium versions.

Answer (score 0):

Current  RenderDoc (1.17) having some BUG or issue with injection process.

You can try with lower version of renderDoc 1.13.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).